# Bootstrap modal send request using post

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I can send request to server using this code,

```
$('#wideModal').modal({remote: '/view/code-101'});
```

But it is using Get Method.

How can I send request using Post method?
I have multiple data to be sent in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

> This option is deprecated since v3.3.0 and has been removed in v4. We
>   recommend instead using client-side templating or a data binding
>   framework, or calling jQuery.load yourself.

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $.post( "/view/code-101", function( data ) {
        $('#myModal .modal-body').html( data );
    });
});
```